# GA4 - Custom Dimensions not available

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics, google-analytics-4

I have created a lot of custom dimensions using User scope,

but when I try to add a comparison using them, its unavailable showing the message "**no data currently available for this dimension**".

Its been a couple days since I've created it.
And I'm using Firebase.setUserProperties to sendo this data

What should I do to be available to use this dimensions?

I've created custom dimensions in Firebase Custom Definitions page

Comment: After creating the custom dimensions you should wait for at least 48 hours so that Google can get updated with the new changes